# Wrap natbib macros \citep and \citet

Tags: errors, natbib, xparse

How can I patch the `natbib` commands `\citep`, `\citet` and the like? I have tried `xparse` (MWE below), `etoolbox` (the `\pretocmd` and `\apptocmd` commands) and `xpatch` (the `\xpretocmd` and `\xapptocmd` commands) without any measureable success.

This is an attempt to find an automatic workaround for the error [\pdfendlink ended up in different nesting level than \pdfstartlink](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1522/8057) that occurs when a link spans two pages. (Even with newest `hyperref`, I'm seeing the error in twocolumn format.) The intention is to wrap all occurrences of `\citep...{...}` and the like into an `\mbox{}`. **Note**: This is not for publishing, this is just for making sure that intermediate states of my LaTeX document in development compile cleanly. I don't want to fix things that probably disappear anyway when the document is released.

**EDIT**: Originally, I was thinking that this would be a very simple thing to do, open-and-shut.
What makes LaTeX behave so oddly in this particular case?

Another way to solve the practical issue behind this is to use [Non-breaking space in \citet using natbib?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4542/8057)
However, this doesn't work for some reason in my case (`natbib` + `hyperref` + `babel`; sorry, no MWE here...) Yet another way would be to restrict the link to a single word in the reference (e.g., to the year), or to add a Wikipedia-style link icon instead of marking the entire reference as clickable.

### MWE (also [on GitHub](https://github.com/krlmlr/lm-template/tree/xparse-citep))

The following code gives me the error shown below:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}

\let\oldcitep=\citep
\RenewDocumentCommand{\citep}{O{} O{} m}{\oldcitep{#3}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\citex}{O{} O{} m}{\oldcitep{#3}}

\begin{document}
  \citep{SomeRef}
\end{document}
```

### Error message

```
Runaway text?
\citep code {}{}{SomeRef}{SomeRef}{SomeRef}{SomeRef}{SomeRef}{SomeRef\ETC.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
\l__xparse_args_tl ...omeRef}{SomeRef}{SomeRef}{So
                                                  meRef}{SomeRef}{SomeRef}{S...
l.12   \citep{SomeRef}
```

What baffles me most: When I replace `\citep` by `\citex` in the document body, the document compiles.

Comment: I haven't done any testing, but does the hyperlink stuff also occur with the modern package `biblatex`? For your own documents, `biblatex` is far better and flexible. For publication, the chance is high that they will simply ignore your fix.

Comment: `citep` can take a starred form, internally there is some stuff going on, very different macros for the open ( and the closing ) and the cite in between.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I still need to take a closer look at BibLaTeX. -- This is more for "continuous integration" (aka compiling "unstable" states of the document for preview). During development of a document, I really don't mind somewhat sloppy typesetting **as long as the document compiles properly**, which it doesn't in this case. I'll add some clarification and add another more precise question about non-breaking references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `\LetLtxMacro`: the documentation of the `letltxmacro` package tells why. See also [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro?s=2|1.5960)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro\oldcitep\citep
\RenewDocumentCommand{\citep}{O{} O{} m}{\oldcitep{#3}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\citex}{O{} O{} m}{\oldcitep{#3}}

\begin{document}
  \citep{SomeRef}
\end{document}
```