# How to prevent line break within a (multiple) citation

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, line-breaking, citing

I sometimes cite two or three references. When the citation is at the end of the line, latex inserts a line break. How can I prevent this from happening?

I already tried what was suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4550/23871)

---

**Note**: I use the package `natbib`, if I do not use `cite[nobreak]` instead of `natbib`, I get the desired result.
However, I would like to continue using `natbib`, if possible.

Here is a MWE (if the citation does not get broken at your machine insert random gibberish of various length):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\NAT@spacechar}{~}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

A really really really really really really really really long sentence, foo \cite{lamport94,foo,bar}.


\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{lamport94}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \emph{\LaTeX: a document preparation system},
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd edition,
  1994.

\bibitem{foo}
  Mr. Foo,
  \emph{\LaTeX: a document preparation system},
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd edition,
  1994.

\bibitem{bar}
  Mr. Bar,
  \emph{\LaTeX: a document preparation system},
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd edition,
  1994.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could put the whole `\cite` command in an `\mbox`.

Comment: I would prefer a solution that involves editing only the preamble. `wc`counts 503 occurances of `\cite` in my document's sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both approaches described here are taken from [Stefan Kottwitz's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4550/5872) to [*Non-breaking space in \citet using natbib?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4542/5872).

## The `\mbox` approach

You can redefine `\cite` to be wrapped in a `\mbox` with

```
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\mbox{\oldcite{#1}}}
```

Or, even better, do so with the [`letltxmacro`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/letltxmacro) package (See [*When to use \LetLtxMacro?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88007/5872))

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldcite}{\cite}
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\mbox{\oldcite{#1}}}
```

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldcite}{\cite}
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\mbox{\oldcite{#1}}}

\begin{document}

A really really really really really really really really long sentence, foo \cite{lamport94,foo,bar}.

A shorter sentence, foo \cite{lamport94,foo,bar}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{lamport94}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \emph{\LaTeX: a document preparation system},
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd edition,
  1994.

\bibitem{foo}
  Mr. Foo,
  \emph{\LaTeX: a document preparation system},
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd edition,
  1994.

\bibitem{bar}
  Mr. Bar,
  \emph{\LaTeX: a document preparation system},
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd edition,
  1994.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

> [image: minimal working example screenshot]

## The `\NAT@spacechar` approach

Instead of redefining `\NAT@spacechar` to an unbreakable space, we should increase the penalty in the `\NAT@separator` macro (which is defined as `\penalty\@m`, a lower penalty than the one applied with `\nolinebreak` [`\@M`]). So we should redefine `\NAT@separator` to

```
\renewcommand{\NAT@separator}{\NAT@sep\nolinebreak}
```

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\NAT@separator}{\NAT@sep\nolinebreak}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

A really really really really really really really really long sentence, foo \cite{lamport94,foo,bar}.

A shorter sentence, foo \cite{lamport94,foo,bar}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{lamport94}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \emph{\LaTeX: a document preparation system},
gg  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd edition,
  1994.

\bibitem{foo}
  Mr. Foo,
  \emph{\LaTeX: a document preparation system},
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd edition,
  1994.

\bibitem{bar}
  Mr. Bar,
  \emph{\LaTeX: a document preparation system},
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd edition,
  1994.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as in the `\mbox` approach.

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer. Both approaches work well.

Comment: Nice answer, I was just coming back to say the same thing, but you've done it perfectly.

Comment: For the `\mbox` approach it is also helpful to redefine the `\cite` command to work also with addtional arguments, so you can use something like `\cite[page 15]{lamport94}`. So better use `\renewcommand{\cite}[2][]{\mbox{\oldcite[#1]{#2}}}`

Comment: For me the `\mbox` approach did not work well. I am using `natbib` package with `abbrvnat` bibliography style in a double column article. And when I cite e.g. 3 papers in a multi citation, they end up sticking out of the column.