# bringing cite (package cite) without line breaks to work

Tags: citing, cite-package

I will ask a new question:

I created a working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}    

\usepackage[nobreak]{cite}                   
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\section{lorem}
lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem\cite{loremlorem}, lorem lorem lorem.

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{literatur}

\end{document}
```

This gives [image]

Even without hyperref, it does not work. The bib file contains:

```
@MISC{loremlorem,
  title={lorem lorem lorem lorem},
  author={lorem lorem, lorem lorem},
  year={2222},
  publisher={lorem lorem lorem lorem}
}
```

I would expect, what is written in the documentary under Line breaks:

http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/cite/cite.pdf

It clearly does a line break in the citation.

Solution: Apalike **not** supported, but still no warning or error as output.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The issue of cite breaks and the issue of cleaning up your list of packages are two separate things, and a solution for one issue will probably be unrelated to a solution for the other issue. Which one do you want to ask about? If it is the list of packages, then the general strategy is to remove everything you don't actually use in your document. If it's the citing, then you can check the manual for the `cite` package or try to find some related questions like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261832/how-to-prevent-line-break-within-a-multiple-citation.

Comment: What is it that is not working here? (Your choice of filler does not make it particularly clear, but I think everything is working fine.) Please clarify what behavior you expected/intended and how the observed behavior differs from that.

Comment: All your silence makes me wonder, if I should use package cite any further.

Comment: The `cite` package is supposed to be used with bibliography styles that generate numeric-style citation call-outs. In contrast, the `apalike` bibliography style can output only authoryear-style citation call-outs.

Comment: So, does that mean, that whenever I thought i was using cite as package, it was not used? What package is used then? I mean, there are not much left...

Comment: Is there any answer to the question, which package is used, when cite is not used?

Comment: Here's an answer: [What is the default bibliography package and backend in LaTeX?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/361645). There is no default package. LaTeX provides minimal bibtex support without using any package, but most people use a package (`natbib` being the most popular, but `biblatex` a close second.)  See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701).

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have completely misunderstood the meaning and purpose of the `nobreak` option of the `cite` citation management package.

The `cite` package is meant to be used with bibliography styles that generate numeric-style citation call-outs, e.g., `[3]` and `[22]`. If the `nobreak` option is set, there won't be a line break either before or after the citation call-out.

However, you would appear to be using the `apalike` bibliography style, which can generate only authoryear-style citation call-outs. All bets are off as to what will happen if you use it in conjunction with the `cite` package. For sure, there's no reason to believe that the `nobreak` option will perform as (mis-guidedly) expected.
The title of the package's user guide reads "The `cite` package: well formed numeric citations". And on page 3 of the same user guide, one finds "If your citations are not numeric, and not of any near-numeric sortable form, then you should probably not use `cite.sty`".

The remedy? Either switch to a bibliography style that can create numeric-style citation call-outs, or stop using the `cite` package and, in its place, start using a citation management package such as `natbib`.